# Is there a way to compare a date stored as a string with the tm structure included in the ctime library?

Tags: c++, string-comparison, ctime

In my c++ project about an Airline Reservation System, I have a class member variable for the date stored as a string (i.e. "4/20/2022") and now I need to store the time as well so I added  ctime library. The problem is I cannot compare them because the ctime structure for date&time gives the date   as separate member variables.

Is there a way to compare them?

Here is an example:

```cpp
time_t ko = time(nullptr);
struct tm time_date_struct = *localtime(&ko);
struct destination_structure {
    int offer_id,seat[size];
    std::string departure;//store time
    std::string arrival;//store time
    std::string from_day; // date as string (4/20/2022)
    std::string to_day; // date as string (4/21/2022)
    destination_structure* next;
};

//...

if(current->from_day < time_date_struct && current->to_day && current->departure < time_date_struct.tm_hour) {
    //...
}
```

update
[compile this sample](https://godbolt.org/z/z9rE5rqvn)

Comment: Side note: [take a look at `chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) as a replacement for `ctime`. If your compiler is up to date, it's got a lot of date and time parsing and handling utilities that will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: You need to parse a string representation of the date into a `ctime` structure, so that you can compare them. Can you do that?

Comment: Sidenote, your first usage of `struct` is redundant. For the second `struct`, you might consider declaring it outside of the function.

Answer (score 2):

- For **C++20 `<chrono>`**, see the bottom half of this answer.

---

> `ctime` structure gives them as separate member variables.

First, there's no structure named `ctime`. You were describing `std::tm`.

---

To create a `std::tm` from given values(year, month, day), you would do something like:

```cpp
int year = 2022, month = 2, day = 2;

std::tm calendar_time{};
calendar_time.tm_year = year - 1900;
calendar_time.tm_mon = month - 1;
calendar_time.tm_mday = day;
```

This would assign year, month, and day correspondingly, while keeping the hour, minute, second as 0. Note that you need to minus a number for year and month, because `std::tm` uses 1900 as the base year, and January as the base month.

Similarly, you can assign hour/min/sec to `calendar_time` with `.tm_hour`/`.tm_min`/`.tm_sec`.

However, `std::tm` can't be used to compare with another `std::tm`. Instead, you would need to first convert them into a `std::time_t`:

```cpp
auto time_since_epoch = std::mktime(&calendar_time);
```

Now you can compare the time you create with current time:

```cpp
auto now = std::time(nullptr);

if (now > time_since_epoch)
    std::cout << "time_since_epoch was in the past!";
else
    std::cout << "time_since_epoch will be in the future!";
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/vocGM4WE8

---

Alternatively, you can format a string from `std::time` with the help of `std::put_time`:

```cpp
auto now = std::time(nullptr);

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now), "%D");
auto now_str = ss.str();
```

This would create a string in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`. Now you can do a string comparison between this and other strings. However, this is not recommended, as this could easily fail if your strings are not formatted in the exact same way(which will be a problem in your case, since you stored the date as `4/20/2022` instead of `04/20/2022`).

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bz36TPfzq

---

## C++20 `<chrono>`

With the `<chrono>` library, creating a date/time object became really simple :

```cpp
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto another_date = std::chrono::month{2} / 22 / 2022;

if (now > std::chrono::sys_days{another_date})
    std::cout << "another_date was in the past!";
else
    std::cout << "another_date will be in the future!";
```

That's all you need!

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bMzv9crxh

---

And you can easily add the time to the date as well:

```cpp
auto date_time = sys_days{month{2} / 22 / 2022} + hours{4} + minutes{13} + seconds{40};
std::cout << date_time;  // prints: 2022-02-22 04:13:40
```

Sad news is not all compilers fully supports the c++20 `<chrono>` yet. A workaround is to use the [`date`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library, written by the same author of `<chrono>` , for now.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/sWzo5GrE1

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/z9rE5rqvn

please check this sample to understand my idea
this is the simplest way to convert string to int

and let me know if there another way

Comment: @Ali The idea seems fine. You probably can rewrite the do-while into a for loop if you want. The only problem is don't do `s[i] != '\0'`. `std::string` aren't guaranteed to be ended with `\0`. Instead check `i < s.size()`.

Comment: @Ali Also utilize built-in functions, such as `string::find` to find `'/'` character, and use things like `from_chars` to convert the string into number: https://godbolt.org/z/Pnn75naE9

Comment: @Ali This can be even further simplified with C++20: https://godbolt.org/z/MMzeWzeK1

Answer (score 0):

[chrono::time_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) data type can be used for comparing time, calculating durations etc.

Your should parse your string into into this data type first, as well as you'll need to format it back to the string according to the  fomat you need maually.

For example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


static std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> parse_time(const std::string& str)
{
    std::stringstream in;
    if( '/' == str[1] ) {
        in.put('0');
    }
    in << str;
    std::tm tmp = {};
    in >>  std::get_time(&tmp, "%m/%d/%Y");
    if(in.fail()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Date parsing failed");
    }
    return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t( std::mktime(&tmp) );
}

static std::size_t diff(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>& start,const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>& end)
{
     return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::days>(end - start).count();
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& to,const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>& what)
{
    std::time_t tmp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(what);
    to << std::put_time( std::localtime(&tmp), "%d %b %Y" );
    return to;
}


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> lhs =  parse_time("4/20/2022");
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> rhs = parse_time("4/21/2022");

    std::cout << "Left Hand Statement date: " << lhs << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Right Hand Statement date: " << rhs <<  std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    if(lhs < rhs) {
        std::cout << lhs << " is before " << rhs << std::endl;
    }

    if(rhs > lhs) {
        std::cout << rhs << " is after " << lhs << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << diff(lhs,rhs) << " days between " << lhs << " and " << rhs << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ideally you would want to use `parse` and `format` directly: https://godbolt.org/z/d6cTYxnP7, instead of converting them to `time_t`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep you'll need full futured C++20 compiler and library for this. Unfortunetelly it may not be availble. Offcause it is not a big deal to rpleace  `std::get_time` with `std::chrono::parse`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/z9rE5rqvn

please check this sample to understand my idea
this is the simplest way to convert string to int
and let me know if there another way

Comment: @Ali That looks like a very cumbersome way of interpreting a date string. Even if you decide to do it manually, something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zfa8Mv1bT) would certainly be simpler.